# My data does not convert to time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

My data contains several measurements in one day. It is stored in CSV-file and looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgKGf.jpg)

The V1 column is factor type, so I'm adding a extra column which is date-time -type: `vd$Vdate <- as_datetime(vd$V1)` :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo3ak.jpg)

Then I'm trying to convert the vd-data into time series: `vd.ts<- ts(vd, frequency = 365)`

But then the dates are gone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbsSI.jpg)

I just cannot get it what I am doing wrong! Could someone help me, please.

Comment: ts is normally used for monthly quarterly or annual data, Use zoo or xts.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip. I'll try.

Comment: Your dates are not gone. If you run the following you should be able to see your data organized by time.

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are gone because you need to build the ts dataframe from your variables (V1, ... V7) disregarding the date field and your ts command will order R to structure the dates.

Also, I noticed that you have what is seems like hourly data, so you need to provide the frequency that is appropriate to your time not 365. Considering what you posted your frequency seems to be a bit odd. I recommend finding a way to establish the frequency correctly. For example, if I have hourly data for 365 days of the year then I have a frequency of 365.25*24 (0.25 for the leap years).

So the following is just as an example, it still won't work properly with what I see (it is limited view of your dataset so I am not sure 100%)

```
# Build ts data (univariate)
vs.ts <- ts(vd$V1, frequency = 365, start = c(2019, 4)
# check to see if it is structured correctly
print(vd.ts, calendar = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally my time series is working properly. I used

```
ts <- zoo(measurements, date_times)
```

and I found out that the `date_times` was supposed to be converted with `as_datetime()` as otherwise they were `character` type. The `measurements` are converted into  `data.frame` type.